# How to split program into files- class c++

Tags: c++, class, matrix, split

Guys I'm bit confused now, I'm trying to split program into file.h file.cpp and main.cpp, here's example of my code:

```
//file.h//

class matrix
{
   private:
      class rcmatrix;
      rcmatrix *data;

   public:
     class Cref;
     class Size_Check{};
     matrix();
    ~matrix();
     matrix(const int rows, const int cols, const double num);
};

class rcmatrix
{
    private:
      rcmatrix(const rcmatrix&);
      rcmatrix &operator =(const rcmatrix&);

    public:
      int rows;
      int cols;
      double **mat;
      int n;
      rcmatrix();
     ~rcmatrix();
};

//file.cpp

matrix::rcmatrix::rcmatrix()
{
    rows=0;
    cols=0;
    mat=NULL;
    n=1;
};
matrix::rcmatrix::rcmatrix(const int r, const int c, const double num)
{
    //instructions.

};
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class matrix::rcmatrix’

error: ‘class matrix::rcmatrix’ is private

error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
matrix::rcmatrix(const int r, const int c, const double num)
```

I know it won't work this way but I tried many other solution but without results, so thanks for any tips/advice for c++ a beginner.

Comment: (a) Did you have your program in one big file already and then try to split it, or was it already split? (b) What lines did the errors occur on?

Answer (score 2):

When declaring the nested class outside of the containing class, you must use its full name `class matrix::rcmatrix`.

Otherwise the compiler believes that you want to declare another, totally separate, class.

Comment: okey got it thanks, but can you tell me what's wrong with this third error?